# Download arquivo via ashx

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ashx

Preciso fazer um método Javascript que chame um ashx (generic handler) que retorna um array de bytes (um arquivo). Este arquivo pode ser XML, TXT ou PDF. Até aí eu resolvi o problema, mas quando o arquivo não existe, sou redirecionado para outra página, mas quero apenas exibir um alert com a mensagem de erro.

```
function GetFile(idAction, chave, fileType) {
    window.downloadfile = function (e) {
        window.location = "MyHandler.ashx?parameter1="
            + idAction + "&parameter2=" + fileType + "&parameter3=" + chave;
    }
    downloadfile();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema com o seguinte código:

```
function GetFile(p1, p2, p3) {
    ShowLoadDiv();
    setTimeout(function () {
        var url = "/MyHandler.ashx?p1=" + p1;
        if (GetRequestReturnStatus(url)) {
            window.open(url);
        }
        HideLoadDiv();
    }, 500);
}

function GetRequestReturnStatus(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();   

    if (http.status == 404 || http.status == 403 || http.status == 500) {        
        ShowMessage("nFailure", "some error message");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```